# Git delete some files in working tree after rm --cached and moving between branchs

Tags: git, commit, gitignore, checkout, rm

When I follow these steps, file in working tree is deleted while that should not happen :

From a new local repo

```
git init
```

I create some files

```
touch file1.txt | touch file2.txt
```

I want to ignore file1

```
echo file1.txt > .gitignore
```

I staged and commit

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

I create a new branch (whitout checkout)

```
git branch dev
```

I was wrong, I want to ignore file2 too ! So I unstaged file2

```
git rm --cached file2.txt
```

I put file2 in gitignore

```
echo file2.txt >> .gitignore
```

I staged and commit

```
git add .
git commit -m "file2 in gitignore"
```

I move to dev branch (do nothing else)

```
git checkout dev
```

I come back to master (do nothing else)

```
git checkout master
```

file2.txt was deleted in my working tree !

What am I doing wrong ?? :(

Is file2.txt is deleted because I checkout from branch where .gitignore is diffrent ?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `.gitignore` applied to already-tracked files?

Comment: I know that .gitignore does not work on files already tracked.
That's why I'm trying to remove it from index BEFORE adding it to .gitignore. did I miss something ?

Comment: Ah, I see, we both did. Checkout deletes files that were part of the previous checkout and aren't part of the new one, so `file2.txt` must have already been tracked.  Part-of-the-checkout to not-part-of-the-checkout only happens for tracked files, ***after*** which they're not tracked (because they've been deleted) and then `.gitignore` will stop them being mistakenly re-added by a wildcard add-everything search.

Answer (score 2):

Looks strange right?

`git rm` works with two different levels,

- remove file from working directory
- remove file from git staging index [understand staging index](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-git-index-4821a0765cf)

`rm --cached` will mark the file as deleted in the staging index only.It will keep the file in working directory as it is.[See more here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-rm)

Then the magic happens with the command `git checkout`

as per the official documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).
it says

> Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index

Which means it will update the `working directory` with the content of the `staging index`.Since you have removed the file from staging index with the command `git rm --cached` then the working directory will be replaced with `staging index` content by the command `git checkout master`.

Comment: Yes really strange! I've lost important files because of this behavior.
I thought that checkout only switch between branchs, without touching the working tree, but no.. Thank you now I understand better.
In my example, do you know how can I remove file2.txt from the index without losing it later ?

Comment: The problem with this answer is, it suggests that checkout will *always* make the working tree match the target commit - which is incorrect.  IF the file were untracked  in the state before the checkout, it would be left alone even though it's not in the target commit.  Also, a lesser issue, but it's misleading to say that a file is "marked as deleted in the index".  The file is removed from the index.

Comment: @ElNino - In the scenario you describe, you did not lose important files.  They're still committed in the dev branch and you can retrieve them from there.  As a general rule, git will not throw away information without warning, with very few exceptions (where a command by definition says "throw such-and-such information away")

Answer (score 1):

I assume your expected behavior, since you have ignored `file2.txt`, is that git will not delete it when switching branches.

But on the branch you're leaving, `file2.txt` is not ignored; in fact it can't be since it's indexed.  And in moving from there to `master`, one of the changes is removal of `file2.txt`.

It's an edge case where the "correct" behavior is debatable.  Sometimes one might expect (or at least want) one thing, and other times one might expect the other.

But what you're observing is the documented behavior of git.

Note that if you *also* remove `file2.txt` from `dev`

```
git checkout dev
git rm --cached file2.txt
git echo file2.txt >> .gitignore
git add .
git commit
```

then switching between branches afterward leaves `file2.txt` untouched.  And if committing `file2.txt` was a mistake in the first place, then removing it from all branches makes sense, at a minimum.

The problem with that suggestion is, depending on what else happens on each branch, it might lead to merge conflicts.  They'd be fairly simple to resolve, but it could still get annoying.  For that reason (or other reasons) you actually might want to consider doing a history edit, especially if these commits haven't been pushed / shared with other developers yet.

**NOTE** that if you do this, you want to make sure you're recovered the working tree copies of `file2.txt`.  (If you don't, it will still be possible (for a while) to recover them afterward, but not as easy.)  So once you have those files safely recovered

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch :/:file2.txt' -- --all
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think I understand the issue now ... Can you confirm by looking at this diagram : [Git issue diagram](https://ibb.co/DwKBmRH). and tell me if there is a better way to represent that behavior ?